# Get rid off duplicate rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following query returns duplicate rows, how to get rid off them:

```
select a.code, b.daytime, b.created_date 
from ov a, CURVE b 
where b.curve_object_id = a.object_id 
order by b.daytime
```

What I'm looking for is the best way to extract object name(in my case it's code) from second table where object_id the same in two tables?

Comment: In TSQL there is distinct but I am not sure about Oracle

Comment: This is not clear. What constitutes a "duplicate"? In the text you say you want to "extract" (whatever that means) object name (in your case it's code), but in the query you select code AND daytime AND created_date. So which is it - do you want code, or do you want all three? And what are "duplicates" - rows with the same code? (That is not the definition of "duplicates" - duplicates are rows where ALL values are equal - but I am guessing you may be using "duplicates" in a non-technical way).

Comment: sorry for not being clear about dublicate rows, table ov is table that only stores single code name and associated object id with code name, table curve is daily data so it can be several records with same code name but different dates (daytime column).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `group by` to eliminate the duplicate rows as follows?

```
select a.code, b.daytime,b.created_date 
    from ov a, CURVE b 
    where b.curve_object_id=a.object_id 
    group by a.code, b.daytime,b.created_date 
    order by b.daytime
```

Comment: Do you have duplicate rows because you have duplicate data? Or do you have duplicate rows because you have a missing join condition? I have seen cases where either of these conditions has been "fixed" with a GROUP-BY. And it works fine for a small test dataset. But you may find yourself in a world of hurt when the data set gets large. Perhaps you can elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: to Tumen_t : thanks, this works fine. to BobC: There is no duplicate data in table curve, probably because I have missing join condition. So what you are saying group by is not good option for large dataset, what would the then best for large dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Always use modern explicit JOIN syntax.

That said, you can use `distinct` in your selection:

```
select distinct a.code,
    b.daytime,
    b.created_date
from ov a
join CURVE b on b.curve_object_id = a.object_id
order by daytime
```